# Hide Combobox value using javascript

Tags: javascript, combobox

value I have a combobox that contains the ff:
   value1
   value2
   value3

Now, I want to hide the value2 from the combobox. I have this code but it seems not to work correctly:

```
function hidevalue(strAcc)
{
    var value = document.getElementById("cmb_Sample")
    var i;
    for(i=value.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(value.options[i].value == strAcc)
            value .options[i].style.display= "none";
    }
}
```

I only want to hide the item, not to remove it as I will be needing the combobox values for some parts of my page.

Thank you

Comment: Don't you mean `if(value.options[i].value == strAcc)` ?

Comment: I don't think you can hide it, but you can disable it by setting disabled attribute

Comment: i guess so, but hiding it is much better so I really want it that way.

Comment: It seem to work in Chrome and FF, if you don't care about IE - your function works

Comment: I don't think you can hide an item from combobox. Its just the nature of the control. You need to remove and add it when needed. This link might help. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d87fdf75-fc0e-4950-a8b2-b27eecde34b0/hide-item-in-combobox?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: Poornima, right, i guess the only way is to remove and add it back. I am just looking for a more optimize solution.